# Same version number for different Windows versions

Tags: c, winapi

In this [page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724832%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), there is something like this:

> Windows Server 2008   6.0
>
> Windows Vista 6.0

[`GetVersionEx()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724451%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) returns the version number (i.e. 6.0), but as you can see, this number can map to two different Windows versions!

So is there's a way to know exactly what Windows version I have?

Comment: That's because it actually is the same version.  Same kernel, just tuned differently.  Use OSVERSIONINFOEX.wProductType to distinguish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [GetVersionInfoEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724451.aspx) API returns a fully populated [OSVERSIONINFOEX structure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724833.aspx) (if requested). The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724833.aspx) contains a complete table, alongside instructions on how to distinguish between OS versions with identical version numbers:

> The following table summarizes the values returned by supported versions of Windows. Use the information in the column labeled "Other" to distinguish between operating systems with identical version numbers.

For your particular example you would need to compare `OSVERSIONINFOEX.wProductType` against `VER_NT_WORKSTATION`. If it is equal, you're on Windows Vista, otherwise you are on Windows Server 2008.

To get reliable results for Windows 8.1 and above, your application needs to be manifested to be compatible. Instructions on manifesting an application for Windows 8.1 and above are available at [Targeting your application for Windows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn481241.aspx).

Sample manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly manifestVersion="1.0" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" xmlns:asmv3="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
    <assemblyIdentity 
        type="win32" 
        name=SXS_ASSEMBLY_NAME
        version=SXS_ASSEMBLY_VERSION
        processorArchitecture=SXS_PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE
    />
    <description> my foo exe </description>
    <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
        <security>
            <requestedPrivileges>
                <requestedExecutionLevel
                    level="asInvoker"
                    uiAccess="false"
                />  
            </requestedPrivileges>
        </security>
    </trustInfo>
    <compatibility xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:compatibility.v1"> 
        <application> 
            <!-- Windows 10 --> 
            <supportedOS Id="{8e0f7a12-bfb3-4fe8-b9a5-48fd50a15a9a}"/>
            <!-- Windows 8.1 -->
            <supportedOS Id="{1f676c76-80e1-4239-95bb-83d0f6d0da78}"/>
            <!-- Windows Vista -->
            <supportedOS Id="{e2011457-1546-43c5-a5fe-008deee3d3f0}"/> 
            <!-- Windows 7 -->
            <supportedOS Id="{35138b9a-5d96-4fbd-8e2d-a2440225f93a}"/>
            <!-- Windows 8 -->
            <supportedOS Id="{4a2f28e3-53b9-4441-ba9c-d69d4a4a6e38}"/>
        </application> 
    </compatibility>
</assembly>
```

Answer (score 0):

Some [version numbers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724832%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) correspond to both a client and server release of Windows.

You can use the [IsWindowsServer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn424963%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function to distinguish between client and server versions of Windows, combine that with the version number and you have the exact version.

However if you're trying to detect whether some feature is supported, checking the version numbers isn't the recommended way, you may want to use `LoadLibrary` and `GetProcAddress` instead to check for features.

Comment: But how to distinguish "Windows Server 2003" from "Windows Server 2003 R2"?

Comment: @user4582812 By checking for the differences you actually care about, rather than checking the version number.

Comment: @user4582812 If you really want to do that, then take a look at the [Win32_OperatingSystem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394239%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) class. All the info is there, down to the build number.